# Create SubReport for each Row in DataTable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Report with a DataSet as the DataSource.
The DataSet consists of 2 Tables. The "Main Table" with one row contains the glaobal Information whereas the other Table countains multiple Rows with the detail info.
What I want now is, that a Subreport is repeated for each Row in the "Details" Table.

e.g.:

DataSet:

```
TableGeneral
row1

TableDetails
row1
row2
```

Report:

```
Report: Fields form TableGeneral.row1
Subreport1: Fields from TableDetails.row1
Subreport2: Fields from TableDetails.row2
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is having something like this:

```
TableGeneral.row1.ReportHeader

TableDetails.row1.Header
TableDetails.row1.Description

TableDetails.row2.Header
TableDetails.row2.Description

.additional TableDetail Rows if present
.
.

TableGeneral.row1.ReportFooter
```

Any techniqe to do this is suffice.

Comment: Does this need to be a subreport or can you just group on the "TableGeneral"?

Comment: Unfortuneatly i have not much experience in Crystal Reports so i dont really know what is the right solution for this task. I edited the question to describe what i want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that TableGeneral is linked to TableDetails on TableGeneral.ID = TableDetails.TableGeneral_ID:

- Insert a group into your report on TableGeneral.ID:

  - Select `Insert > Group...` from the Crystal Report Designer menu.
  - In the Insert Group dialog, select TableGeneral.ID in the dropdown on the common tab.
  - click OK at the bottom of the Insert Group dialog.
- In the Group Header section that has appeared, there will probably be a Group #1 Name. Delete this and drag and drop the desired TableGeneral fields from the Field Explorer into the Group Header section.
- Drag and drop the desired TableDetails fields from the Field Explorer into the Details section.

If you now click on Preview, you should see your report output in something like the desired format.

Comment: Ok. I got it to work. At least the Preview looks right. But now when i create the report there is no data displayed. Although the DataSet is filled... Any suggestions. Just to be clear. I made a Group and the only setup i did was to chose the primary key of the General Table, wich is as you stated in your answer linked in that way with the DetailsTable. Then i dragged the detail Fileds in the Details section... I am under the impression i didnt get the mapping GeneralTable/DetailsTable right...